# Travis build not finishing properly

Tags: node.js, travis-ci, jasmine-node

I am trying to setup a travis build, except that the test script isn't executing fully. It starts, but then travis says it's exited with code 0 when it's still in the middle of running.

[Here](https://travis-ci.org/vidr-group/vidr-core) is the travis page.
I'm using jasmine-node to run the tests, and it works just fine on my computer.

Let me know if I'm missing any vital information.

Thanks,
-tlf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the error was caused by my attempting to use mongodb without actually starting it first. Adding

```
services:
  - mongodb
```

to my .travis.yml file fixed the issue.